Show/Hide Column Display name using a Condition using JSON Not PowerApps
I want to remove the title "Please upload the personal image if needed", if the Visa Support is "Yes", and show it if the Visa Support is "No".
I want to make it using JSON> However, I am unable to do so, Any ideas ??
Just Tell me where to look, I don't want someone to write me the code!!


Is "Please upload the personal image if needed" SharePoint default Attachments field or any custom column/field you created?

This was the Attachments Field, I renamed it into "Please Upload Personal Image If needed", and now i want to make condition on its visibility . If the Visa Support is Yes. Then the part at the bottom , should be blank

Unfortunately, currently it is not possible to show/hide attachments field conditionally using JSON formatting or conditional formulas.

Unfortunately, currently it is not possible to show/hide SharePoint default Attachments field conditionally using JSON formatting or SharePoint conditional formulas.
Attachments field is not shown in "Edit columns" pop up section hence you cannot add conditional formula for it:

Related documentation: Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library form.

Also, you cannot show or hide fields on SharePoint list form using "Body" layout JSON formatting.

Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration only allows defining one or more sections and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

Documentation: SharePoint JSON formatting - Configure custom body with one or more sections.

I agree with Ganesh Sanap. I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.
